# Camel-JPA: No option to send a command message to the JPA component (like in JDBC comopnent)

Tags: jpa, apache-camel, camel-jdbc

In the Camel-JDBC component, we can send a select statement as a body to the jdbc endpoint, which returns the results.

Below sample code is from the Camel-JDBC website:

```
from("direct:projects")
   .setHeader("lic", constant("ASF"))
   .setHeader("min", constant(123))
   .setBody("select * from projects where license = :?lic and id > :?min order by id")
   .to("jdbc:myDataSource?useHeadersAsParameters=true")
```

Why is such an option not present in the Camel-JPA component?

Using JPA endpoint as a consumer will poll the database. But, all I want is to just get the data once.

Answer (score 1):

Camel doesn't have that feature because the JPA supports named queries.  You can do something along these lines.

```
from("direct:start")
    .pollEnrich("jpa:" + MyEntity.class.getName() + "?consumeDelete=false&consumer.namedQuery=myNamedQuery&consumer.parameters=#params", new MyAggregationStrategy())
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "call my entity toString method ${body}");



//spring context OR you can use camel registry
<util:map id="params" key-type="java.lang.String">
    <entry key="param1" value="1"/>
    <entry key="param2" value="2"/>
</util:map>

//JPA model
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
@NamedQuery(name = "myNamedQuery", query = "SELECT t FROM MyTable t WHERE t.columnName1 = :param1 AND t.columnName2 = :param2")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PrimaryKey", updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String primaryKey;

    @Column(name = "Param1", length = 5)
    private String param1;

    @Column(name = "Param2", length = 5)
    private String param2;

    //removed setters getters, hascode, equals, and toString for brevity
}
```

Comment: But, this will still poll the DB right? I just want to query the DB once, not poll it.

Comment: No this solution isn't polling.  The 'pollEnrich' name is slightly confusing.  Here is a comparison between enrich and pollEnrich: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098466/camel-content-enricher-enrich-vs-pollenrich

Comment: For clarification Yes you will just call the database once and replace the contents of your exchange.  Please feel free to try it out.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. My only concern with jpa is that the default behavior of "consumeDelete" being true seems very dangerous, just in case someone forgets to override it.

Comment: @ndsurendra  I completely understand that the first time I tried the component I hit that issue.  Lucky this issue can easily be caught before an application goes to production.  If your still somewhat nervous you could always write a quick maven or gradle plugin that found JPA endpoints and verified that  consumeDelete="false".