# How to read from database using Camel JPA

Tags: jpa, apache-camel

I'm about write a CRUD application using Apache Camel, very much like the example at:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/rest-apache-camel

But I would like to use JPA instead of just JDBC.

I've looked at the Camel JPA component and thought I could use it. But to read from the database it expects me to define a consumer endpoint.

I would like to do something like the following from the JDBC example:

```
from("restlet:/user/{userId}?restletMethods=GET")
.setBody(simple("select * from user where id = ${header.userId}"))
.to("jdbc:dataSource");
```

I.e. call the JPA component as a producer.

Is this possible?

I found the following post, which suggest using pollEnrich from the content enricher pattern. 
[Camel mid-route jpa consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983480/camel-mid-route-jpa-consumer)

Could that be a way to make it work? Feels like I'm working against how it was intended to be used.

Thanks!
E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to pass the parameter into camel-jpa consumer to let it know what kind of data need to be pull from database. I think you need to use the camel-jdbc component this time.

Comment: I thought I could use the namedQuery option. But its parameters can't be changed per request, right? (And that's why you are saying that it's hard to pass parameters? Just to make sure that I'm not misunderstanding your answer.)

Comment: The parameters cannot be changed by the message header or the message body. I afraid you have to use camel-jdbc to do the job.